# Server-side handling of braintree payments in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, payment-gateway, braintree

I'm developing a web application which has a Node.js backend. I'd like to implement payment system provided by your Braintree API. The classical mechanism that is describe on the website:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/node

assumes the following:

1) First a client issues a request to my server for the client token

2) My server responds with a token generated using my Braintree credentials (merchantId, public/private key)

3) The client passes that token, along with the payment form data to the Braintree server

4) The Braintree server responds with an authorization token (payment nonce)

5) The client sends the payment nonce back to the server

6) The server uses that nonce and the amount specified by the client to realize the transaction

7) Braintree server is notified about the new transaction

While it is a nice and clear description, I have a little bit different flow in mind, and I wonder if it is possible to realize. I'd like to exclude any communication between the client and the Braintree server, and manage all token/nonce business server-side. It would look as follows:

1) The client sends all payment data to the server in one payment request

2) The server generates client token and manages any necessary 
communication with Braintree itself, without the client involved

3) The server realizes the payment and returns the result info to the client

In other words, this method:

```
 gateway.transaction.sale({
    amount: '5.00',
    paymentMethodNonce: "nonce-from-the-client",
    options: {
      submitForSettlement: true
    }
  },
  function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
      if (result.success) {
        console.log("Transaction ID: " + result.transaction.id)
      } else {
        console.log(result.message)
      }
    } else {
      console.log(err)
    }
  });
```

requires a `nonce-from-the-client`, and I'd like to get it from Braintree using the server only, not the client.

The idea is to simplify the process from the point of view of the client, so that the frontend only has to send one request with a form and nothing else. Is such an idea even possible to implement for now? The thing is, that in the provided example, the client executes some client-side script braintree.js which is not really usable for a Node.js server:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2#send-payment-method-nonce-to-server

And that's where I'm stuck at. Any ideas?

Comment: Full disclosure: I work for Braintree. I would not recommend using the server-only flow where you send all payment method data to your server before passing it to Braintree. The advantage of the client token and nonce flow we provide is that credit card numbers do not touch your servers, but  Braintree's secure servers. Credit card data passing through your servers requires a higher level of PCI compliance.

Comment: Thank you, Jessica, I have already contacted the Braintree support, and learned exactly the same. Makes sense ;) Your comment should be an answer